# How to localize a DateTime.DayOfWeek?

Tags: .net, datetime, localization, .net-2.0, globalization

I can't figure out how to properly localize `DateTime.DayOfWeek` in .NET 2.0.

Example:

```
DateTime date = DateTime.Now;

// Works fine
string localizedDate = date.ToString("D", new CultureInfo("fr-FR"));

// Nope...
string localizedDay = date.DayOfWeek.ToString("D", new CultureInfo("fr-FR"));
```

I'm restricted to .NET 2.0, is that the problem?

Comment: I've updated your post but in the future, please try to update your code snippets, so that they look like code, rather than standard text.  The easiest way to do this is to highlight your sample code, and click the code format button (which is the one with the picture of two brackets.)

Comment: @RLH Apoligies, clicked post a bit fast there. Thanks for your edit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`DateTimeFormatInfo` is [supported since .NET 2.0](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.datetimeformatinfo%28v=vs.80%29.aspx), so this is not the case.

Try this instead:

```
DateTime.Now.ToString("dddd", new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("fr-FR"));
```

Comment: I was about to share this information. FYI, the problem is that you are accessing an enumeration type and trying to format it as a date.  What you want to do is process the full date value.  Using the `"dddd"` format options explicitly tells the text processor to only write the day name part of the date.

Comment: Thanks a lot, was stubbornly trying to get DateTime.DayOfWeek.ToString to work... Your reply also pointed me to this page in MS's documentation, for future readers sake : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx (lists all Custom Format Specifiers ).

Answer (score 2):

Your second example:

```
string localizedDay = date.DayOfWeek.ToString("D", new CultureInfo("fr-FR"));
```

is using an [Enumeration Format String](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c3s1ez6e.aspx), in which the "D" format specifier means "return the shortest representation possible".

You could try:

```
string localizedDay = new CultureInfo("fr-FR").DateTimeFormat.DayNames[(int)date.DayOfWeek];
```

Comment: The speed and willingness to help in the coding community will never cease to amaze me... Many thanks, your example is way more helpful than the MS .NET documentation.